# What combination of bluetooth mouse and keyboard work ok with the BQ M10 tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bluetooth, phone

Can we create a list of devices known to work with the M10 tablet that other users can take as reference when they want to buy a kit for themselves?

Comment: I understand why you asked this question but it is not really a good fit for our site. We would like to focus on actual questions that have practical answers.

Comment: @jokerdino: I see your point that this may be to broad for this site, but it is nevertheless and important topic as convergent devices are a core focus for the Ubuntu community. Any suggestions where to host a list of compatible bluetooth devices?

Comment: @tomoqv maybe a post on [Ubuntu Discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com), or the community wiki (http://help.ubuntu.com/community)?

Answer (score 2):

I personally use HP X4000B - mouse & Logitech Bluetooth Multi-device Keyboard K480, I've found both to be extremely reliable

Answer (score 2):

I use without problems the Logitech K380 Keyboard and the SONY VGP-BMS15 Bluetooth Mouse

Answer (score 2):

Adding an Apple Mighty Mouse, a Logitech MX1000 Keyboard/Mouse set (special keys not all supported yet) and a Logitech diNovo Mini to the mix of known-to-work devices.

Answer (score 2):

The Logitech K380 Multi-device bluetooth keyboard works perfectly for me, I love it, and a few more people do so too: http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/the-best-bluetooth-keyboard/

I was not so lucky with a few pointer devices I had lying around: the first-gen Apple Magic Trackpad and the Microsoft Bluetooth Mobile Mouse 3600 are not working just yet.

With my bq m10 tablet I'm also using a slightly forked version of the Lego Folding Tablet Stand shown here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Lego-Folding-Tablet-Stand/

Answer (score 1):

I tested the logitech k480 Bluetooth keyboard and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Microsoft Wedge Bluetooth Keyboard and Mouse with the Meizu MX4 and Nexus 7.

I don't suspect any issues with the *bq M10*.

Answer (score 1):

I got a TECHGEAR® [Active Strike Pro] Slim Bluetooth Wireless UK QWERTY Keyboard with Mouse Touchpad from Amazon. Works really well. Ok feel to it. Only real downside is when using mousepad it has a constant habit of bringing up the today scope, which can be annoying. Tried it on the bq M10.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully paired and used the following mice and keyboards with my Aquaris M10:

- Logitech keyboard K380, works without issues and connects and
  disconnects instantly
- Exibel HB087 Bluetooth Keyboard with Touchpad,
  works fine, but doesn't connect/disconnect as quickly as the K380
- HP Bluetooth Mouse Z5000, works without issues and connects instantly,
  but somewhat slower to disconnect

I have managed to pair the following devices that aren't discovered by the bluetooth system settings on the M10 (OTA-10.1):

- Microsoft Universal Foldable Keyboard
- Microsoft Designer Mouse

Please read https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-system-settings/+bug/1576986 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-keyboard/+bug/1577436 to find out about my experience with these devices that don't work "out of the box" with Ubuntu Touch.